# Data Base Sharding In django using MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, sharding

Hi I have been trying to improve the db performance and had done some basic research regarding having a db partition and db sharding and also having 2 dbs one for write and other for read .

However i found out that the db sharding is the best way out of all as the mapping provided by sharding is dynamic that is one of the requirement to put it bluntly i have provided the 2 cases below

Case 1:- we need to get all the transaction of a user (which is huge)
Case 2:- we need all the data for a particular time interval for all the user (which is again huge)

Because of the above scenerios I'm looking to implement db sharding

Note:- I have already segregated some db into multiple databases already and they sit on different machines so i want it to be applied to all those multiple databases

What I'm Looking for :

1. Any link that could be helpful
2. Any snippet code that could be helpful

Django==3.2.13
MySql == 5.7

Comment: Please elaborate on "transaction for a user".  Is this something that can be `SUM()'d` up?  Or is it, say, order processing details?  What kind of data?  Will you be returning a million rows?  Choke!

Comment: Consider transactions as payement records and i will be returning milliomns of rows and that will get converted to csv file from django api passed to frontend

Answer (score 0):

Let me define some terms so that were are "on the same page":

**Replication or Clustering** -- Multiple servers having identical datasets.  They are kept in sync by automatically transferring all writes from one server to the others.  One main use is for scaling *reads*; it allows many more clients to connect simultaneously.

**PARTITION** -- This splits one table into several, based on date or something else.  This is done in a single instance of MySQL.  There are many myths about performance.  The main valid use is for *purging* old data in a huge dataset.

**Sharding** -- This involves splitting up a dataset across multiple servers.  A typical case is splitting by user_id (or some other column in the data).  The use case is to scale *writes*.  (On pure MySQL, the developer has to develop a lot of code to implement Sharding.  There are add-ons, especially in MariaDB, that help.)

**Your use case**

Your "2 dbs one for write and other for read" sounds like Replication with 2 servers.  It may not give you as much benefit as you hope for.

You are talking about `SELECTs` that return millions of rows.  None of the above inherently benefits such, even if you have several simultaneous connections doing such.

Please provide some numbers -- RAM size, setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and dataset size (in GB) of the big `SELECTs`.  With those numbers, I can discuss "caching" and I/O and performance.  Performing multiple queries on the *same* dataset *may* benefit from caching on a *single* server.

Replication and Sharding cannot share the caching; Partitioning has essentially no impact.  That is, I will try to dissuade you from embarking on a technique that won't help and could hurt.

Please further describe your task; maybe one of the techniques will help.

P.S., Replication, Partitioning, and Sharding are mostly orthogonal.  That is any combination of them can be put together.  (But rarely is.)

Comment: Hi Rick Thanks a lot for explaining the concepts in so much detail now let me tell you the task it's basically to get the data from multiple tables which are related via Foreign Keys and we also add some data from different tables if a particular column has a specified value and then just download the CSV. size of CSV could be 1 GB as of Now

Comment: A 1GB CSV might load into a table of about 3GB.  Most machines can easily handle a dataset of that size.  If the machine has 8GB of RAM, then there might be very little I/O.  With less RAM, things are still possible, but _might_ run slower.  Another useful metric is "queries per second".  100 is usually possible; 1000 may take some performance work.  Do you have any `SELECTs` written yet?

Comment: i have written the query using Django ORM

Comment: @SachinRajput - Are the tables full of `BIGINT` columns that contain only little numbers?  My 1GB->3GB may be an underestimate.  BIGINT takes 8 bytes, regardless of the value.

Comment: csv  have variety of values like Integer FLoat, boolean and String in it

Comment: `INTEGER` means `INT`, which is 4 bytes.  Not so bulky.

Comment: Thats what but still to extract 40K data from multiple table its taking 45seconds which is very slow

Comment: @SachinRajput - How many tables?  Do they have the same columns?  If so, we need to discuss having a single table instead of multiple identical tables.  Can the data be summarized daily, then sum the subtotals to get the grand total?  In some situations that can result in a 10x improvement.  Please provide more info on the data so I can help you in one of these directions.